# Append String with HEX characters from a String

Tags: python, string, hex, character

I haven't found a way to solve this problem yet:

From a user Input the script receives a string, e.g.:

> "ABCD.00.00"

The . indicates an hex character, the script should output the follwing string:

> "ABCD\x00\x00"

I tried the following:

```
cmd = "ABCD.00.00"
if "." in cmd:
    splitted = cmd.split(".")
    cmd = splitted[0]
    i = 1
    while i < len(splitted):
        cmd = cmd+"\\x"+splitted[i]
        i = i + 1
return(cmd)
```

But the returned string has two backslashes, and so the hex characters can not be recognized:

> "ABCD\\x00\\x00"

Does anybody has a clue to solve this problem?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is happenning because unicode strings can't be just appended directly to a string(utf-8) as per the documentation.

Encodings don’t have to handle every possible Unicode character, and most encodings don’t. The rules for converting a Unicode string into the ASCII encoding, for example, are simple; for each code point:

If the code point is < 128, each byte is the same as the value of the code point.
If the code point is 128 or greater, the Unicode string can’t be represented in this encoding. (Python raises a UnicodeEncodeError exception in this case.)

if you will print the output of the function it will give you the desired output as

```
>>> a="ABCD\\x00\\x00"
>>> print(a)
ABCD\x00\x00
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, thank you very much for your response. I know that the printed string is looking like my desired output, but I want to send the Symbol \x00 (NUL) instead of the "\\x00".

Answer (score 0):

I just tried an quick and dirty way by using a lookup table:

```
ascii2hex = (['00', '\x00'], ['01', '\x01'], ['02', '\x02'], ['03', '\x03'], ['04', '\x04'],
        ['05', '\x05'], ['06', '\x06'], ['07', '\x07'], ['08', '\x08'], ['09', '\x09'],
        ['0A', '\x0A'], ['0B', '\x0B'], ['0C', '\x0C'], ['0D', '\x0D'], ['0E', '\x0E'], ['0F', '\x0F'],
        ['10', '\x10'], ['11', '\x11'], ['12', '\x12'], ['13', '\x13'], ['14', '\x14'],
        ['15', '\x15'], ['16', '\x16'], ['17', '\x17'], ['18', '\x18'], ['19', '\x19'],
        ['1A', '\x1A'], ['1B', '\x1B'], ['1C', '\x1C'], ['1D', '\x1D'], ['1E', '\x1E'], ['1F', '\x1F'],
        ['20', '\x20'], ['21', '\x21'], ['22', '\x22'], ['23', '\x23'], ['24', '\x24'],
        ['25', '\x25'], ['26', '\x26'], ['27', '\x27'], ['28', '\x28'], ['29', '\x29'],
        ['2A', '\x2A'], ['2B', '\x2B'], ['2C', '\x2C'], ['2D', '\x2D'], ['2E', '\x2E'], ['2F', '\x2F'],
        ['30', '\x30'], ['31', '\x31'], ['32', '\x32'], ['33', '\x33'], ['34', '\x34'],
        ['35', '\x35'], ['36', '\x36'], ['37', '\x37'], ['38', '\x38'], ['39', '\x39'],
        ['3A', '\x3A'], ['3B', '\x3B'], ['3C', '\x3C'], ['3D', '\x3D'], ['3E', '\x3E'], ['3F', '\x3F'],
        ['40', '\x40'], ['41', '\x41'], ['42', '\x42'], ['43', '\x43'], ['44', '\x44'],
        ['45', '\x45'], ['46', '\x46'], ['47', '\x47'], ['48', '\x48'], ['49', '\x49'],
        ['4A', '\x4A'], ['4B', '\x4B'], ['4C', '\x4C'], ['4D', '\x4D'], ['4E', '\x4E'], ['4F', '\x4F'],
        ['50', '\x50'], ['51', '\x51'], ['52', '\x52'], ['53', '\x53'], ['54', '\x54'],
        ['55', '\x55'], ['56', '\x56'], ['57', '\x57'], ['58', '\x58'], ['59', '\x59'],
        ['5A', '\x5A'], ['5B', '\x5B'], ['5C', '\x5C'], ['5D', '\x5D'], ['5E', '\x5E'], ['5F', '\x5F'],
        ['60', '\x60'], ['61', '\x61'], ['62', '\x62'], ['63', '\x63'], ['64', '\x64'],
        ['65', '\x65'], ['66', '\x66'], ['67', '\x67'], ['68', '\x68'], ['69', '\x69'],
        ['6A', '\x6A'], ['6B', '\x6B'], ['6C', '\x6C'], ['6D', '\x6D'], ['6E', '\x6E'], ['6F', '\x6F'],
        ['70', '\x70'], ['71', '\x71'], ['72', '\x72'], ['73', '\x73'], ['74', '\x74'],
        ['75', '\x75'], ['76', '\x76'], ['77', '\x77'], ['78', '\x78'], ['79', '\x79'],
        ['7A', '\x7A'], ['7B', '\x7B'], ['7C', '\x7C'], ['7D', '\x7D'], ['7E', '\x7E'], ['7F', '\x7F'])
```

I'm searching the string (e.g. '00') in the table and replace it with the corresponding entry ('\x00').

This fixed my problem, but I'm pretty sure that there is a cleaner way.